# OpenSSH Ubuntu Upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, pci-dss

We are currently using an EC2 (AWS) instance with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, we are trying to perform a PCI compliant procedure and we had an error with OpenSSH being in an old version, so we have decided to update it.

I have compiled and installed a newer version of OpenSSH (8.0*), unfortunately when I run a "scanssh" using my IP I still get the older version, the funny thing is when I run again "ssh -V" I get the latest version.

I have read in the internet that it might be because my SSH is installed as a port not as a package, if someone knows the solution, I will be happy to use it, thank you!

Comment: Was the ssh(d)-service reloaded/started? `sshd` might still be running the old version in order to not interrupt existing connections, while `ssh`, i.e. the client program to connect, is already allowing to use the updated version.

Comment: I have restarted the ssh service, when I use ssh -V I get 8.0 but when I use telnet localhost 22 it still says 7.6

Comment: Then maybe go more into detail on how you installed and restarted the service. Possibly something was missed.

Comment: No, as I mentioned before, the Ubuntu Security Team has probably limited the OpenSSH upgrades to 7.6, I don't know how to bypass that limit.

For the installation, I have compiled an 8.0 OpenSSH version and then I have stopped and started the service.

Comment: Compiled source code from where? Replaced which executables? Restarted the service how? Modified which systemd service files? No one can know what you did if you refuse to provide details. How should anyone find an error then?

Comment: I have followed this tutorial : https://www.tecmint.com/install-openssh-server-from-source-in-linux/

Comment: What version do you get when running `sshd --help`. Are the change times of the executables for `ssh` and `sshd` the same? The guide does not say anything about restarting the service. How did you do that?